# How to Send Email using c# on Go Daddy Server

Tags: c#, email

I'm attaching the code below:

I get an Error in this Code But This Code Perfectly Working at My Local 
IIS.But not Working at Any Server,

My Code was
 Email-Code

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress("From Mail ID");
msg.To.Add("To Mail ID");
msg.Subject = "Hello world! " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
msg.Body = "hi to you ... :)";
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.Port = 587;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("From Mail ID", "******");
client.Timeout = 20000;client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: And what error your got ?

Comment: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. But this Code was Working at Local IIS

Comment: Any Update? For this Question

Answer (score 0):

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();

mail.To.Add("*****@gmail.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("domain email");
mail.Subject = "Test Email";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Body = "Test";

SmtpServer.Host = "dedrelay.secureserver.net";
SmtpServer.Port = 25;
SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;           

try {
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does so people that are new to the technology have a chance to understand and re-use it.